# Replacing <img> tags in cycle2.js

Tags: jquery, html, image, replace, cycle2

I want to use the cycle2.js slider. Each element I want to cycle through is a div element containing multiple article tags.

Can I replace the img tags with a div? How?

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    >
    <!-- prev/next links -->
    <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
    <div class="cycle-next"></div>
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg"> <!-- Can I convert img tags to div elements? -->
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

I'm now trying to get JS to display three of the articles, and change the three being shown after a certain time has passed. The page with this code considered displays one article at a time in an odd (broken) position. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="cycle-slifdshow" data-cycle-slider="div">
  <div class="three-at-a-time">
    <article> ...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
  </div>
  <div class='three-at-a-time>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says yes http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/faq/#non-image

> I want to use slides that are not images. How do I tell Cycle2 what my
> slides are?
>
> Use the data-cycle-slides attribute to provide a jQuery
> selector which identifies the elements within the container that are
> slides. For example, if your slideshow is a ul with li slides you
> would set the attribute like this: data-cycle-slides="li"

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="li">
     <li><img src="path/to/some/image1.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="path/to/some/image2.jpg"></li>
     <li><img src="path/to/some/image3.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just noticed stackoverflow does not allow you to reply with formatted code in your response. I will edit my original question to reflect my position. Thanks for the answer!